# Rational Cohomology of Hilbert scheme of two points on a three folds

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

As stated in the title, does anybody know a paper or a reference on where to find something about cohomology of Hilbert scheme of two points on a three folds, even if its only $\mathbb P^3$?.
I am looking for something that gives the generators of the rational cohomology.

Comment: Isn't just a blowup of the 'diagonal' in the quotient $X\times X/S_2$ by the symmtric group in that case?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez  Yes you are right. I am trying to find this fully worked out if possible.

Comment: Nakajima's "Lectures on Hilbert schemes"?